# A possible loophole on the 3-Clause BSD license

Tags: licensing, bsd-license

In a license.txt file, this:

```
 Part of this program uses the following clause

 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright 
 notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in 
 the documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
```

is definitely different from this:

```
 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright 
 notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in 
 the documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
```

When applying the second clause of a 3-clause BSD license without "Part of this program uses the following clause", does bundling the library mean that my created application has to be governed by the 3-clause BSD license also?  E.g. my program should have no warranties, etc?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not lawyers and this is a very specific legal question. See [when is a software licensing question on topic?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7265/when-is-a-software-licensing-question-on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That clause in the BSD license *does not* extend the license to the rest of your application.

What that clause means is that, at least, you must have a section in the documentation of your application along the lines of

> Parts of this application are governed by the BSD license:
>   < text of the BSD license goes here >

It is usually appreciated if you also identify which parts are under the other license, but that is not a requirement.